# Why do games sometimes skip frames in monogame/xna?

Tags: c#, xna, 2d, monogame

This is a simple project created from MonoGame Cross-Platform Desktop template. I created a ball Texture2D and tried to make it move.So I added some code to the Update function.

```
position.X += 3;
```

And then in the Draw function

```
_spriteBatch.Begin();
_spriteBatch.Draw(ballTexture, position, Color.White);
_spriteBatch.End();
```

I can see the ball flashing sometimes.
Why is that and what can I do to make it not skip frames?

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace SimpleTest
{
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        private GraphicsDeviceManager _graphics;
        private SpriteBatch _spriteBatch;

        private Texture2D dirtTexture;
        private Vector2 position;
        private int direction = 1;

        public Game1()
        {
            _graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            IsMouseVisible = true;
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            _spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
            dirtTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("dirt");
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);

            if (position.X > 600)
                direction = -1;
            else if (position.X < 100)
                direction = 1;

            position.X = position.X + direction * 3;
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here
            _spriteBatch.Begin();
            _spriteBatch.Draw(dirtTexture, position, Color.White);
            _spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show more of the Draw() function in other classes?

Comment: I submitted all the code. It is very short and there are no other classes. That's why I don't think it should skip frames and I'm sure there's nothing wrong with my computer

Answer (score 0):

I think `base.Update(gameTime);` should only be placed at the very end of the `Update()` Method, Just like `base.Draw(gameTime);`. That way it won't skip any lines.

Comment: I just put it at the end of the Update() Method as you said,but it didn't work.This sprite occasionally shakes as it moves and it looks a little fuzzy

Answer (score 0):

I guess your PC might be running slowly which is the problem, and not your code. To test it, you can replace your Draw method as follows:

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Color color=gameTime.IsRunningSlowly?Color.Red:Color.CornflowerBlue;
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(color);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        _spriteBatch.Begin();
        _spriteBatch.Draw(dirtTexture, position, Color.White);
        _spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

Everything is the same, except now we are colouring the screen as Red instead of the usual blue only if the game is in fact running slow (Which is due to your PC). We can know this by the gameTime variable as shown in the first two lines of the method. Test it out and see if you can see the game background going red when the "frame-skipping" happens.

I did test your exact code in my PC and it was working fine. Needless to say, I did use some other png I had instead of the "dirt" Texture2D you used but I don't think that it should be necessary.

Comment: I added the code to my Draw method,and the background color didn't turn red.Is there any other reason for this problem?

Comment: @echo That's really strange. Then could it be that you're loading a large image as "dirt" for this? If the game did not turn red, it's definitely not frame skipping (that is, the game loop of a frame takes more time than required to maintain the game at 60FPS; which is not the case here since gameTime.IsRunningSlow is never true), so please clarify what exactly is strange when you're drawing the image?

Comment: I have no problems running games on my laptop，but "frame-skipping" happens on my computer.My computer has better CPU and GPU than laptop.Is it possible that the problem is caused by the higher resolution of the computer screen?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's due to GC. You could use my -almost- garbage free build to verify.
You can install the updated SDK from [here](https://github.com/nkast/XNAGameStudio/tree/master/MG%20SDK) or the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/nkast).